# presenting View Controller from AppDelgate

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, storyboard

I tried have an application with UTabBarController in storyboard.

It displayed fine. however, I would like also to show firstTimViewController if user launch app for first time. hence, I need to show this view on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in Appdelgate.

I've used below code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = window.rootViewController.self.storyboard;
    StartupViewController *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StartupTableIdentifier"];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:svc animated:NO];
```

it gives me the following error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target .'**

Comment: when you debug it, is storybaord nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set up the storyboard for the app?  The name of the storyboard should match.  Click on the project, click on the target, and verify in the summary tab that the Main Scoreboard name matches the name of the .storyboard in the project.

To make sure you have an inital view controller, make sure inital view controller is checked:

[image]

Comment: I changed the above code to : UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                                @"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    StartupViewController *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StartupTableIdentifier"];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:svc animated:NO]; now, it's not showing error. but also nothing happens. it just show the UITabBar immediately without showing the first controller.

Comment: OK, make sure the storyboard has a first controler set.  In the storyboard, Click on the storyboard, click on the view controller you want to be the first view controller, then under the atrributes inspector, check "Is Inital View Controller"

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have an NSUserDefaults setting that you set from the firstTimViewController (after it is dismissed) and just check for that setting in the Storyboard's rootVC (The first TabBar VC).  When the app launches for the first time, check and see if the user has seen and acknowledged that firstTimeVC and if not, present it from the TabBar VC.

I would leave the AppDelegate alone and do the logic in the TabBar VC.

Comment: I tried to do what you mentioned so I added this code:   UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
    StartupViewController *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StartupTableIdentifier"]; it works fine If it triggered from for example tab on button, but it  didn't work from ViewDidLoad method. where could I put this code on the rootVC.
    
    // configure the new view controller explicitly here.
    
    [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: The didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in the AppDelegate should just return YES.  No reason to put code in there to instantiate your storyboard as you can do that from the project settings.  This post will show you what I am talking about.  http://irockios.com/?p=32

Comment: but in which method of rootVC shall I put the code to present the firstVC. I tried to put in ViewDidLoad but it didn't work, it only works when I put on on method triggered by button, which is not applicable to my needs.